# la memoria no se pudo read

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

[image]
no pude conectar al data base desde workbench

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Quizás no tienes suficiente memoria RAM. 2. ¿Has intentado reinstalar el programa?

Comment: cuando instalaste el workbench, instalaste tambien mysql?, porque veo que estas usando xampp, a veces suele generar conflicto tener 2 instalaciones.... además puedes usar dbeaver,, una alternativa a workbench,  saludos.